# Making a Stack of int Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I'm trying to make a stack of integer arrays, like so:

```
stack<int[2]> stk;

int arr[2] = {1,2};
stk.push(arr);
```

however, Visual C++ gives me the error

```
error C2075: 'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces
```

and MinGW gives me the error

```
error: parenthesized initializer in array new
```

The error seems to be coming from `stk.push(arr)`. What does the error mean, and how would I properly make a stack of integer arrays?

Comment: You can't use raw arrays in containers. For one, they're not copyable/moveable.

Comment: stack<vector<int> > stk;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With C++11 arrays you can do this:

```
#include <stack>
#include <array>

stack<array<int, 2>> arrs;
arrs.push({1, 2});
```

As mentioned in a comment to the question, it is also possible to replace `array<int, 2>` with `vector<int>`. However, `array<int, 2>` achieves what you where describing with a fixed size container (and lower memory usage.)